# How do I select the last 5 minutes of data from an ms access db using pyodbc?

Tags: python, sql, ms-access, pyodbc

I have the following query (python pyodbc on windows 7 accessing an access db .mdb):

```
SQL = 'SELECT acq_spill_3_1_sec.time_stamp, acq_spill_3_1_sec.float_value 
    FROM acq_spill_3_1_sec WHERE acq_spill_3_1_sec.time_stamp > DateADD(n,-5,Now())'
```

The `DateADD` doesn't seem to work. I get the following error:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('07002', '[070021] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few
parameters. Expected 1.
```

I've tried single, double and no quotes around the n, but that makes no difference.

Answer (score 2):

Two problems: 1) Put double quotes around the `n` parameter. 2) Put square brackets around the `time_stamp`. (Access interprets your underscore in the `time_stamp` field as a special character under certain circumstances. The query parser does its best to interpret special characters, but sometimes it gets it wrong. The square brackets help the parser disambiguate the field name so it does the parsing correctly.)

Just my opinion, I would use `DateDiff` instead, since it makes more sense when you read it:

```
SQL = 'SELECT time_stamp, float_value FROM acq_spill_3_1_sec WHERE DateDiff("n",[time_stamp],Now()) <= 5'
```

I find it's a lot easier to build the queries yourself inside Access and try them out there first to make sure they work before writing them in code. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help. But that doesn't seem to work. Get the same error.

Comment: What do you get when you try writing and running the same query in Access? I tried this out myself in Access 2007, and it worked.

Comment: If you get a working query within Access, then you can call it directly from your code by passing an 'EXECUTE QueryName' as your SQL string.

Comment: Please say more about this: "Access interprets your underscore in the time_stamp field as a special character under certain circumstances."  What are the circumstances where an underscore within a field name confuses the database engine?

Comment: I wish I could ... the query parser in Access oftentimes has very unpredictable behavior. If I suspect problems, I just put square brackets around anything that seems like it might confuse the parser. See http://tech.kateva.org/2008/06/access-2003-and-bugs-with-special.html for some examples. Note that this page doesn't mention problems with underscores, but they do exist (like in the OP's question).

Answer (score -1):

According to the examples on the DATADD MSDN page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx), try using

```
DATEADD(minute, -5, NOW())
```

Comment: Thanks. But that doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: T-SQL answers do not help with Access questions.